# Convert Stereo Soundtrack -> 5.1 DTS

Tags: windows, windows-vista, software-rec

How to convert stereo mp3 songs into 5.1 mp3 song

is there any free software to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GUIDE: Converting stereo to 5.1 surround for FREE](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1011274#post1011274)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after playing them via a 5.1 amp, you could use AC3Filter to output stereo as 5.1 surround. But it sounds like you actually want to convert the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [V.I Stereo to 5.1 Converter VST Plugin Suite](http://stevethomson.ca/vi/).

Install it on your system and use [Plogue Bidule](http://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/), [Audiomulch](http://www.audiomulch.com/), Steinberg [Cubase](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/start.html) SX or [Nuendo](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/nuendo.html) to convert stereo to 5.1 channel sound.

Comment: I'd suggest adding more details and context to your answer. I didn't downvote it but you didn't really explain the steps required.